# Program that reads file input and displays proportion of the length of the letter and so on

Tags: java, arrays, methods, file-io

I have an assignment due two days and I have been trying a lot of days to do this, but I am burned, tried to come back to it, still no progress.

THE ASSIGNMENT is the following:

Java program that computes the above statistics from
any text file. Here’s what it might look like in action:
Name of the input file: example.txt
The proportion of 1-letter words: 3.91% (74 words)
The proportion of 2-letter words: 18.52% (349 words)
The proportion of 3-letter words: 24.24% (456 words)
The proportion of 4-letter words: 19.80% (374 words)
The proportion of 5-letter words: 11.33% (212 words)
 …
 …
The proportion of 12-letter words: 0.45% (8 words)
Proportion of 13- (or more) letter words: 0.51% (9 words)

Now In order to do this, I thought to divide my program into three methods: Read the method, count the letters and distinguish them and finally display it as the example above. Now that I said that, here is my code right now:

```
 /*like make smaller functions
where each function has one task
like to loop through the file and return an array of words
then use that as input to another function whose purpose is to count the 
letters
and then pass that array into a function for printing that.
*/


import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Autorship {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Name of input file: ");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System. in );
        sc1.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]");
        String fname = sc1.nextLine();
        sc1.close();

        sc1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname));
        sc1.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]");
        String line;
        System.out.println(WordCount(fname, sc1));



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }


}

public static int WordCount(String fname, Scanner sc1) {


    int wordCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
        String line;
        line = sc1.nextLine();

        lineCount++;

        String[] strings = line.split(" ");
        int[] counts = new int[14];

        for (String str: strings)
            if (str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;

        System.out.println("This is counts length: " + counts.length);
        for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)

            System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);



    }

    return 0;


}


}
```

Now please **I do not want the answer, as that would be plagiarism, and I am not that kind of person**, I just want a bit of help to continue to progress, I'm so stuck right now, thanks ^^

Comment: Where is the troublesome point? What does not work as expected?

Comment: So the problem is that it outputs this:
This is counts length: 14
1 letter words: 0
2 letter words: 0
3 letter words: 1
4 letter words: 0
5 letter words: 1
6 letter words: 1
7 letter words: 0
8 letter words: 0
9 letter words: 0
10 letter words: 0
11 letter words and so on , but it repeats it by 14 times,

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adjusted and working version. I commented the lines I edited.

Your code wasn't that bad and it was working quite well. The only problem you had was that you've printed out the letter counts inside the while-loop instead of doing it outside. Therefore it repeated with every new line that was read from the file.

Please note: I strongly recommend to always use curly brackets even though Java syntax allows to not use them with if-statements and for-loops if they're followed by only one line of code to execute. But not using them makes the code harder to read and error prone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Name of input file: ");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System. in );
        sc1.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]");
        String fname = sc1.nextLine();
        sc1.close();

        sc1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname));
        sc1.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]");
        String line;
        System.out.println("WordCount: " + WordCount(fname, sc1)); // edited



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }


}

public static int WordCount(String fname, Scanner sc1) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    final int MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 14; // edited. Better use a constant here.
    int[] counts = new int[MAXIMUM_LENGTH]; // edited. Constant applied

    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc1.nextLine();

        // increment line count
        lineCount++;

        String[] strings = line.split(" ");

        // increment word count
        wordCount += strings.length; // added

        // edited. curly brackets and constant MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        for (String str: strings) {
            if (str.length() < MAXIMUM_LENGTH) {
                counts[str.length()] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // edited / added. finally show the results
    System.out.println("maximum length: " + MAXIMUM_LENGTH);
    System.out.println("line count: " + lineCount);
    System.out.println("word count: " + wordCount);

    // edited. moved out of the while-loop. MAXIMUM_LENGTH applied.
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXIMUM_LENGTH; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);
    }

    // edited.
    return wordCount;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question. Thanks in advance.